# How to describe C# object in Typescript

Tags: c#, typescript

We use ClearScript to extend our apps. We expose various C# objects into JavaScript, using ClearScript's AddHostType and AddHostObject methods.

Recently we've started using Typescript in our Google Apps Script projects and thought it would be good to use it to manage our ClearScript scripts as well.

This has proved to be an interesting experience. We know know about such things as `external.d.ts` and have started to write one to handle the various symbols that we're injecting in from the C# side.

Some things we've been able to work out. For example, in this code

```
function SchTasks(instruction:string) {
  var proc = CSProcess.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\schtasks.exe", instruction);
  return proc;
}
```

this declaration seems to work

```
declare namespace CSProcess {
  function Start(a:string, b:string): any;
}
```

Likewise, with this block

```
that.getMyIP = function () {
  var request = new CSRestRequest();
  request.AddParameter("user", username);
  request.AddParameter("pass", password);
  request.AddParameter("command", "getmyip");
  var response = client.Execute(request);
  return response.Content.trim();
};
```

this declaration appears to work

```
declare class CSRestRequest {
    constructor (str?:any) ;
    AddParameter(a:string, b:string) : any;
}
```

What's puzzling us at the moment is how to declare the following. The symbol is called `CSSettings` and it's an instance of `Dictionary<string,object>`, so it has some methods hanging off it, like `.ContainsKey`. What's the best way to declare this? It can't be `new`ed so it's not a class with a constructor, but it does have methods like a class.

```
var taskName = "\XChecker\M_XChecker_" + (function () {
    if (CSSettings.ContainsKey("/TEST")) {
      return "TEST";
    }
    if (CSSettings.ContainsKey("/PRODUCTION")) {
      return "PRODUCTION";
    }
    return "UNKNOWN";
  }
    ()) + "_" + CSSettings("/TASKRULESETGROUPLUTFKS") + "_" + CSSettings("/INSTANCENUMBER") + "_" + CSSettings("/INSTANCECOLUMN");
```

**LATER**

The following appears to work. What's curious is that VSCode is not reporting a clash of symbol names. Can `CSSetting` really be a function and a namespace at the same time? Apparently, yes.

```
declare function CSSettings(s:string):any;
declare namespace CSSettings {
  function ContainsKey(s:string):boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

declare your dictionary class. and then variable CSSettings with this type

```
declare class IDictionary {
  constructor();
  public ContainsKey(key: string): boolean;
}

declare const CSSettings: IDictionary;

CSSettings.ContainsKey('key');
```

// edit

so what about to create 2 type and merge it? so you will be able to use CSSettings as function and even as object

```
declare type functionType = (key: string) => boolean;
declare const CSSettings: functionType & { ContainsKey: (key: string) => boolean };
CSSettings.prototype.ContainsKey = 1;


CSSettings('key');
CSSettings.ContainsKey('key');
```

Comment: He says it's not instantiable so that declaration is misleading. An `interface` would be appropriate.

Comment: The above doesn't deal with the CSSettings(string) situation which is getting a value from the dictionary.

Comment: its was not clrear for me. CSSettings is not class. but it seems like an instance of a classic dictionary. but it can be interface whatever. Its just sample. Since it is only declaration not implementation does it really matter?